# Tables Are Not Linking. Returning ALL results?

Tags: unique, relationship, powerpivot

on the file I have (link here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cwdli7HG9npIUPg9V_y6v3Brro7vT_9A) I am really struggling trying to link both my tables by "Booking Ref". 
It's clearly the unique identifier between the two, but when I create a pivot from the Data Model, it just takes the sum of everything on Table17 [Sum of Pax].
So if I want to see how many Pax are on a booking flying on British Airways, it tells me "14", which is just the sum of ALL my pax!

I drew up a small table of what the results should look like using vlookups. (My real file is much bigger than this, otherwise I would just do it that way!).

Can anyone help, or advise me what I'm doing wrong? Because to me it seems like it should be a very straighforwards case of [Table2][Booking_Ref]----[Table17][Booking Ref] (many to one).
I even tried creating a table from a ListDistinct formula in case it was a duplication thing.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Table17 - 'one' values

Table2 - 'many' values

Table 17 - create a new calculated column using the 'lookupvalue' function:
=LOOKUPVALUE(Table2[Airline],Table2[Booking_Ref],Table17[Booking Ref])

[lookupvalue for airline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDE1m.png)

You should now have a column with the airline on each row (looking at your data, each booking has a single unique airline so i'm working on the assumption that each booking will only ever have a single airline associated with it)

Next, still on the Table17 tab, write a measure to sum up the Pax values:
paxSum:=sum(Table17[Pax])

Finally, drag in your new calculated column, the booking ref, and new measure.  These should all come from Table17.
[finished product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMY0T.png)